# Webots crashes at startup on Windows

Tags: webots

I downloaded [Webots R2020a revision 1](https://github.com/cyberbotics/webots/releases/download/R2020b-rev1/webots-R2020b-rev1_setup.exe) and installed it on my Windows 10 machine.
The first time I opened it, I got the following error message:

[image: Error Message]

The problem persists on uninstalling and reinstalling the software.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It could be caused by several things:

- graphics card: Some old Intel graphics cards are not supported by Webots and may cause this kind of crash.
- graphics card driver: outdated drivers may cause such crashes. You should check that your graphics card driver is up-to-date.
- conflicting software: some third party software install some DLL in the Windows system32 folder (which is a bad practice) causing some conflicts with Webots if the DLL name is the same as some DLL used by Webots.
- your installation of Webots was somehow corrupted.

Comment: The problem was with my graphics card. For anyone facing the same issue, update your graphics card driver and try again.